# Card flp is not working in safari and its working fine in Mozilla, Explorer and in Chrome

Tags: jquery

I am trying to show flip on my website but its not working in Safari. Below is the code. I guess there is some css issue that do not support safari. In the other browsers its working fine(chrome, mozila, and explore). I've tried some webkit css but its still not working.

Below are the HTML, css and jquery used for the card flip functionality.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var classClicked = 'clicked';
  $('.card-flip').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass(classClicked)) {
      $(this).removeClass(classClicked);
    } else {
      $(this).addClass(classClicked);
    }
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).removeClass(classClicked);
  });
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  user-select: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(#111, #1a1a1a);
}


/* ELEMENT */

.card-flip {
  margin: 20px auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  perspective: 1000px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 450px;
}

.card-flip__flipper {
  transition: .3s ease;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}

.card-flip__content {
  width: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fancy-hover__image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  transition: filter .15s linear .15s;
}

.fancy-hover__fancy {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(55, 66, 78, 0);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: background .15s linear .15s
}

.fancy-hover__fancy:after {
  content: '';
  background: white;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transition: left .15s ease-in-out, right .15s ease-in-out;
}

.fancy-hover__text {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.fancy-hover__element {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 16px;
}

.fancy-hover__element--title {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  transition: bottom .15s ease-in-out .15s, background .15s linear .15s;
}

.fancy-hover__element--subtitle {
  top: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  transition: top .15s ease-out;
}

.fancy-hover:hover .fancy-hover__image {
  filter: blur(2px);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.fancy-hover:hover .fancy-hover__fancy {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.fancy-hover:hover .fancy-hover__fancy:after {
  left: 20%;
  right: 20%;
  transition-delay: .15s;
}

.fancy-hover:hover .fancy-hover__element--title {
  bottom: 50%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.fancy-hover:hover .fancy-hover__element--subtitle {
  top: 50%;
  transition: top .15s ease-in .15s;
}

.card-flip__content--front {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  z-index: 2;
}

.card-flip__content--back {
  background: rgb(44, 44, 44);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  height: 450px;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-flip.clicked .card-flip__flipper {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure class="card-flip fancy-hover">
  <div class="card-flip__flipper">
    <!-- FRONT SIDE -->
    <figure class="card-flip__content card-flip__content--front">
      <img class="fancy-hover__image" src="https://unsplash.it/300/450?image=953">
      <div class="fancy-hover__fancy"></div>
      <div class="fancy-hover__element fancy-hover__element--title">
        <p class="fancy-hover__text">Title</p>
      </div>
      <div class="fancy-hover__element fancy-hover__element--subtitle">
        <p class="fancy-hover__text">Description<br>(click me)</p>
      </div>
    </figure>
    <!-- BACK SIDE -->
    <figure class="card-flip__content card-flip__content--back">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
        takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
    </figure>
  </div>
</figure>
```

Comment: You can just use `$(this).toggleClass(classFlipped)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`backface-visibility` is not supported in Safari, you need `-webkit-backface-visibility`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var classClicked = 'clicked';
  $('.card-flip').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass(classClicked)) {
      $(this).removeClass(classClicked);
    } else {
      $(this).addClass(classClicked);
    }
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).removeClass(classClicked);
  });
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  user-select: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(#111, #1a1a1a);
}


/* ELEMENT */

.card-flip {
  margin: 20px auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  perspective: 1000px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 450px;
}

.card-flip__flipper {
  transition: .3s ease;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}

.card-flip__content {
  width: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fancy-hover__image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  transition: filter .15s linear .15s;
}

.fancy-hover__fancy {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(55, 66, 78, 0);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: background .15s linear .15s
}

.fancy-hover__fancy:after {
  content: '';
  background: white;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transition: left .15s ease-in-out, right .15s ease-in-out;
}

.fancy-hover__text {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.fancy-hover__element {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 16px;
}

.fancy-hover__element--title {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  transition: bottom .15s ease-in-out .15s, background .15s linear .15s;
}

.fancy-hover__element--subtitle {
  top: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  transition: top .15s ease-out;
}

.fancy-hover:hover .fancy-hover__image {
  filter: blur(2px);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.fancy-hover:hover .fancy-hover__fancy {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.fancy-hover:hover .fancy-hover__fancy:after {
  left: 20%;
  right: 20%;
  transition-delay: .15s;
}

.fancy-hover:hover .fancy-hover__element--title {
  bottom: 50%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.fancy-hover:hover .fancy-hover__element--subtitle {
  top: 50%;
  transition: top .15s ease-in .15s;
}

.card-flip__content--front {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  z-index: 2;
}

.card-flip__content--back {
  background: rgb(44, 44, 44);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  height: 450px;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-flip.clicked .card-flip__flipper {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure class="card-flip fancy-hover">
  <div class="card-flip__flipper">
    <!-- FRONT SIDE -->
    <figure class="card-flip__content card-flip__content--front">
      <img class="fancy-hover__image" src="https://unsplash.it/300/450?image=953">
      <div class="fancy-hover__fancy"></div>
      <div class="fancy-hover__element fancy-hover__element--title">
        <p class="fancy-hover__text">Title</p>
      </div>
      <div class="fancy-hover__element fancy-hover__element--subtitle">
        <p class="fancy-hover__text">Description<br>(click me)</p>
      </div>
    </figure>
    <!-- BACK SIDE -->
    <figure class="card-flip__content card-flip__content--back">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
        takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
    </figure>
  </div>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things here :)

- Welcome to the wonderful world of browser compatibility(sarcasm), unfortunately, not everyone uses chrome(oh a perfect world) and some people  * ***shudders*** * still use IE ..... anyway, you have run into a problem where Safari actually does not support `backface-visibility` . Instead you will have to use the webkit equivalent, `-webkit-backface-visibility`.
- jQuery has gotten increasingly better over it's releases, so there is no real need to track status of classes now if it is just for DOM manipulation purposes. instead of this you can simply use the  `$('#yourId').toggle();` or  even `$('#yourId').toggleClass('yourclassname');` which will implicitly keep track of it.